# Is this question eligible to be posted here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627008/rearrange-an-array-so-that-when-written-in-a-space-where-elements-wraps-below-i

As suggested in the comment?

I've been looking questions here and they all seem a bit.. quiz-oriented, which is why I'm still in doubt...

Comment: The user who commented that this belongs to codegolf.se was wrong in my opinion. Questions on-topic here are programming contests. Stackoverflow is the right place to ask your question, you didn't make any mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not belong here, because it is not a contest and not a programming puzzle. It's a general programming question, and they belong on Stack Overflow.

As the tour says:

> Don't ask about...
>
> General programming questions